# looping inside a select tag and echo selected value

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to loop inside a select tag and output the quantity inorder to allow the user to select a quantity from the selection box , but the numbers are printed next to each other ,,how to solve that ? ,,and how to echo the selected item !?

```
 <select name="quantity">
 <div  style="font-
size:13px;position:relative;left:10px;width:80px;height:20px;border-style: 
hidden;background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);color:white;" > </div> 
 <option value="" disabled selected>Quantity </option>
 <option value="quantity"><?php for($i=1;$i<=$row["item_quantity"];$i++)
  {echo 
 $i."<br>";}?></option>

   </select>
```

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
<option value="quantity"><?php for($i=1;$i<=$row["item_quantity"];$i++)
  {echo 
 $i."<br>";}?></option>
```

try this:

```
for($i=1;$i<=$row["item_quantity"];$i++)
{
   // To make a option selected
   $selected = '';
   if( $i == 2 )  // 2 or any value
   { $selected = 'selected="selected"'; }
   echo '<option value="'. $i .'" '.$selected.' >'. $i .'</option>'
}
```

**Explanation:** The issue is, your loop is inside the `option` tag, which is wrong. Put the `option` tag inside the loop.

Comment: this works ,, but it doesn't give me the selected item on form submit

Comment: Is this true ?  if ( isset($_POST["btnac"])){
if ($_POST["quantity"] == $i) {

Comment: I didn't understand ,,then how to submit the form ?

Comment: Mayank Pandeyz  can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your script you have add loop at wrong place

```
    for($i=1;$i<=$row["item_quantity"];$i++)
    {
       echo '<option value="'. $i .'">'. $i .'</option>'
    }
```

Comment: How to submit form in this case ?

Comment: form submit as simple you can got  this select value in php using $_REQUEST['quantity']

Comment: describe your whole script to get more idea.

Comment: and Also describe your requirement

Comment: I just want the user to choose the item from the selection box and I want to echo it ,,,but the difference here ,,there is a loop ,,so how to solve that

Comment: first of all you need to learn more about how to use php with html.........

Comment: i can suggest to you not write whole script . i also say you to display your script here for get more idea.

Comment: And also refer your question what tell.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
<select name="quantity">
     <option value=""  selected>Quantity </option>
     <?php for($i=1;$i<=$row["item_quantity"];$i++) { ?> 
     <option value="<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></option>
     <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: how to submit the form ?